# Yahoo news search API

Tags: api, search, yahoo, yahoo-api

I want to display yahoo news based on search term I provided and for that I have searched yahoo API provides me news content.
But API or RSS feed only give me 10 or something results each time but I want Yahoo API such that it provides me all the results available and if at a time its not possible to send all results then provide me paging parameter so I can request request for other pages if available.

So can any one suggest me such Yahoo API or RSS feed?

Answer (score 0):

No, you [won't be able to do this](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/08/api_updates_and_changes/):

> Other non-BOSS search APIs such as Web Search, Image Search, News
>   Search, Related Suggestion, and Site Explorer APIs will shut down with
>   no further support in YQL. We plan to make these transitions and
>   shutdowns effective by end of [2010].

Use a modern news service instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply,
But is there any other alternate solution to achieve functionality?

Comment: @DharmeshSolanki: It's unlikely a news provider would allow this; you'd be accessing all of their content, but taking away all of their ability to display branding and advertisements. What's in it for them? And what is your goal here?

Answer (score 0):

As Lightness Races in Orbit pointed out, the original Yahoo search services (like [News Search](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/news/V1/newsSearch.html)) were shut down in favor of BOSS.

You might check out the latest release of BOSS which does include [News Search](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/#overview). This is now a paid service, currently at $0.10/1000 queries, and has a limit of 50 returned items for each search term.

You can also check the [Bing Search API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251072.aspx) which includes a News component. I have not used this for any serious work yet but it looks like an option.

In any case, you'll probably find that these are not designed or intended for someone to create a full-blown news site on their own (as Lightness Races in Orbit mentioned), but can still be useful for specific search queries.